# Rails 3 and Devise: Omniauth vs. Facebook Connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, facebook

I am currently using Devise+Omniauth on my Rails 3 app to authenticate users.  My client saw this and doesn't like how omniauth redirects you away from the site. He wants something like on digg.com, which I believe uses facebook connect to authenticate (and opens in a popup instead of redirecting).

What are some arguements for my client to keep him using the Omniauth method? Why is it better than Facebook connect.

And failing that, are there any good resources for logging users in with a facebook connect popup window? Or really anything involving facebook and a popup.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have to ask us for reasons why Omniauth is better than Facebook Connect instead of having them, why are you so certain it's the better option? Secondly, is there some technological reason you can't get Omniauth to work in a popup like Facebook's solution does?

Comment: @ceejayoz: OmniAuth is very particular about how it works with Devise, due to how the authentication process works I think having it open in a popup window would be more work than it's worth.

Comment: I'm not certain it's the better option.  Frankly I spent a fair amount of time getting Omniauth up and running and I don't want to have to throw away all that time just to start again.  I did it to begin with because it seemed to be the industry standard.

Comment: And yes, Ryan Bigg covered my answer on the second part. I'm not even sure if it's possible, and if it is, it's going to be extremely difficult methinks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OmniAuth supports login via the Facebook Javascript SDK, which works through a popup. You just need to include the right files. I don't remember all the details, but this should help:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/120